# Is there a PayPal API which allows for an embedded widget (iFrame) to process PayPal payments without leaving the iFrame?

Tags: iframe, paypal, payment-gateway, gateway

I'd like to create an embedded point of sale using an iFrame that allows visitors to make one time purchases with PayPal.  Presently the Express Checkout API will begin the secure login process before opening full frame.

Is a more robust PayPal solution an option?  We'd like for the visitor to remain within that iFrame while completing their purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into [Express Checkout In-Context](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/) at all?  I haven't played with it myself yet, but that's supposed to be exactly what it's for.